# Yarn - Show dependency chain for warnings when running yarn install on version 2/3

Tags: hadoop-yarn, yarn-v2, yarn-v3

Is there anyway to get more information about the warnings in the "resolution step" when running `yarn install`? Either during the `install` process or afterwards.

The main info I want to get is the dependency chain for each warning. Version 1 would display something like this:

```
warning semantic-ui > gulp > gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
```

but it seems like that chain has been removed in versions 2 & 3. Now I'm seeing more limited messages like this:

```
YN0061: gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
```

I know that `yarn why` can be used to get specific dependency chains after `install`. But that only works one at a time and I'm trying to get everything at once.